# Rails 4 select Uniq

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Tenho as tabela Itens:

> ```
> id   enrollment_id   turma_id
> 11   2               2
> 12   2               3
> 13   2               2
> 14   2               2
> 15   2               3
> ```

Eu quero que o meu resultado seja esse:

> ```
> id   enrollment_id   turma_id
> 11   2               2
> 12   2               3
> ```

Ou seja eu quero todos os itens, mas que não se repita a turma, estou tentando assim:

```
@itens = Item.where(turma_id: @turma.id).uniq
```

Mas não esta dando certo. Continua retornando os repetidos.

Comment: _não esta dando certo_ não ajuda. Mostre a mensagem de erro ou, se houver, o resultado não esperado. Não conheço `Rails` mas não está faltando parêntesis? `uniq()`

Answer (score 1):

Caso você não precise de nenhuma informação além dos campos distintos você pode fazer:

```
@itens = Item.select(:enrollment_id, :turma_id).uniq
```

Nesse caso, são instanciados objetos do tipo Item com id igual a `nil`.

Ou

```
@itens = Item.uniq.pluck(:enrollment_id, :turma_id)
```

Com o `pluck` não são instanciados objetos do tipo Item, mas sim um array de arrays do tipo [enrollment_id, turma_id]. Nesse caso o pluck tem que ser o último método chamado, por isso o uniq vem antes.

Caso você precise dos ids ou de outras informações além que não fazem parte do distinct, em PostgreSQL você pode usar [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
@itens = Item.select('distinct on (enrollment_id, turma_id) *')
```

Caso você queria garantidamente pegar os primeiros registros, você pode adicionar `order` pelo id.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda GuiGS